# Congomongo fetch returns nil

Tags: clojure, congomongo

I have simple app that should return single record from Mongo database.

```
(def movie (m/fetch-one :movie
                        :where {:_id id}))
```

id is correct but i keep getting `nil` as a return from this. 
Here is how my `:_id` looks like

```
:_id #<ObjectId 5245ca7d44aed3e864a1c830>
```

I guess my problem is here somewhere, but I just don't have enough experience with Clojure to find an error

In this case `id` passed to where is `5245ca7d44aed3e864a1c830`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your id is a string instead of being an ObjectId object. To create an ObjectId use the function `object-id`. Note that there is also a `fetch-by-id` fn

Comment: Aha. `fetch-by-id` also returns `nil`. What namespace should I include to use `object-id`

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. Forgot prefix I used when importing congomongo. Works now. Thanks